# React Native - Component Exception

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting an error that says Component Exception(undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.renderScreenComponents') when running my react native. I am trying to create a drawer menu. Before I started trying to implement the menu, everything was working fine.

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import ListView from "./src/screens/components/list_view";
import DetailView from "./src/screens/components/detail_view";
import ScreenA from "./src/screens/drawer/screenA.js";
import ScreenB from "./src/screens/drawer/screenB.js";
import ScreenC from "./src/screens/drawer/screenC.js";

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

// this is the problematic part
renderScreenComponents = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={ListView} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailView} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" children={this.renderScreenComponents} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Screen A" component={ScreenA} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Screen B" component={ScreenB} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Screen C" component={ScreenC} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

I have made sure that there are no typos in any of the files, but I still am not sure what is going on. I would sincerely appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function using const or function keyword.

```
const renderScreenComponents = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={ListView} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailView} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```